# Vue Apollo Graphql get meta tags from wordpress

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, graphql, apollo, vue-meta

I have a problem with add meta information from graphql to vue-meta.

how to from external about.gql information add to vue-meta?
Adding one more gql query I would like to avoid. So I am not so experienced with Vue and Apollo and any help will be good!

Thanks a lot!

about.vue

```
      <ApolloQuery :query="require('../graphql/about.gql')">
    <template slot-scope="{ result: { loading, data } }">
      <div v-if="loading">Loading...</div>
      <div class="" v-if="data">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="p40" v-html="data.pageBy.content"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
  </ApolloQuery>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    loading: 0,
    error: null,
  }),
  metaInfo: {
    // title will be injected into parent titleTemplate
    title: 'About',
    meta: [
      {
        name: 'description',
        content:
          'Epiloge is about connecting in your field of interest. Our vision is to help people share their knowledge, work, projects, papers and ideas and build their network through what they do rather where they live, study or work.'
      },
      {
        property: 'og:title',
        content: 'Epiloge - Build your network in your field of interest'
      },
      { property: 'og:site_name', content: 'Epiloge' },
      { property: 'og:type', content: 'website' },
      { name: 'robots', content: 'index,follow' }
    ]
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve this problem? I'm facing the same issue!